# Run jar from Nautilus - OpenJRE disappeared!

Tags: nautilus, java, jre

Although I'm frequently using the command line terminal, I find it very irritating when I cannot execute applications from Nautilus.

I sometimes write small Swing based Java apps and I've just noticed how the OpenJRE disappeared from the "Open with..." options.

I do have the OpenJRE installed through the OpenJDK.

Screenshots attached. /// actually I cannot! Why do I need a reputation of 10? \\

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add a link to the screenshot.